# Suggestion for "Convert line breaks into HTML" and text editor for corporate website

Tags: 7, input-formats

Previously when developing my own community website in Drupal 6, I've never know what people like when dealing with text editor. So I simply go with Ckeditor and untick `Convert line breaks into HTML` in the Text format options.

But now developing corporate website in Drupal 7. Ckeditor is in early stage (lack of visibility option) and I cannot use wysiwyg module because it has many conflict.

One good choice is use Bueditor. It looks clean and perfect but i must tick `Convert line breaks into HTML` in the Text format options to make it works for paragraphs.

So, should I:

- use wysiwyg editor and untick `Convert line breaks into HTML` ?
- or use Bueditor and tick `Convert line breaks into HTML` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Wysiwyg (or CKEditor) along with most editors and use [Wysiwyg Linebreaks](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_linebreaks) to make the editor work great with existing content, or when switching between editors, and in other circumstances.

Also, Wysiwyg should be pretty stable (I've been using it on a ton of different sites), especially when using it with CKEditor, TinyMCE, or most other editors.

For most of my sites, I have the `Convert line breaks into HTML` option checked no matter what, mostly because I like being able to see/edit content without extraneous paragraph and line break tags all over the place, and so paragraphs don't get run together.